# Can I Format The Date In a Bootstrap Data Table Row?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, date, datatable

I have a bootstrap data table and a date row in the data table.The date displays like "dd.mm.YYYY 00:00:00".But I want to display the date like "dd.mm.YYYY" without time.Can I do that with HTML or javascript?

[image: Data Table]

Comment: yes you can do that with javascript. 
Here are some examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) or [*Format date on bootstrap datetimepicker*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675278/format-date-on-bootstrap-datetimepicker) or any of [*these*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+bootstrap+format+date).

Comment: No,none of these answers solve my problem.And no,it is not duplicate.My question is not about datepicker or something like that.My question is about date format that i use from the database...

Comment: Yes you can format in via JavaScript. Here follow the code written https://editor.datatables.net/examples/dates/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you  @ShivekParmar

Answer (score -1):

Thank you  for your answers and i have found another solution for my problem.

```html
<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
```